# How do I limit only certain users to access specific function in my application?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm using Angular and Java Spring Boot. My question is, where do I make the code changes to allow only certain users to get access for the specific function? Which part on the backend should I touch? As for now, everyone can get access.

I believe this is the code, am I correct? So I need to limit access for a function under the `customers module` called `change-plan`. How do I do it assuming the authorized users are A,B,C,D.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: genRouterLink([RouteConstant.POSTLOGIN, RouteConstant.DASHBOARD]),
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: PreloginComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: RouteConstant.LOGIN,
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: RouteConstant.ACCOUNT_OPENING,
        loadChildren: () => import('./feature/dealer-account-opening/dealer-account-opening.module').then(m => m.DealerAccountOpeningModule)
      },
      {
        path: RouteConstant.FORGOT_PASSWORD,
        component: ForgotPasswordComponent,
      },
      {
        path: RouteConstant.RESET_PASSWORD,
        component: ResetPasswordComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: RouteConstant.POSTLOGIN,
    component: PostloginComponent,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: RouteConstant.DASHBOARD,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: RouteConstant.DASHBOARD,
        loadChildren: () => import('./feature/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: RouteConstant.REGO,
        loadChildren: () => import('./feature/rego/rego.module').then(m => m.RegoModule)
      },
      {
        path: RouteConstant.CUSTOMERS,
        loadChildren: () => import('./feature/customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule)
      },
```

landing.component.html

```
<div class="my-2" *ngIf="(dealer$ | async).userName == 'admin' || (dealer$ | async).userName == 'GCS001'">
   <button class="w-100" mat-raised-button color="accent"
     (click)="navigate([RouteConstant.POSTLOGIN, RouteConstant.CUSTOMERS, RouteConstant.CHANGE_PLAN])">Change Plan</button>
</div>
```

landing.component.ts

```
export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {

  offerSelection: Array<SelectModel> = [];
  dealerAcctBalance: number;
  planSelected: string;
  RouteConstant = RouteConstant;

  @Select(DealerState.getDealer)
  dealer$: Observable<DealerUserModel>;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router,
              private walletRestService: WalletRestService, private store: Store,
              private modalService: ModalService, private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initPlanSelection();
    this.getWalletBalance();
  }

  initPlanSelection(): void {
    this.offerSelection = PlanConstant.OFFER_PLAN_SELECTION.map((plan: PlanModel) => {
      return {
        label: plan.planName,
        value: plan.planKey
      }
    });
    this.planSelected = this.offerSelection[0].value;
  }

  private getWalletBalance() {
    const dealerId: string = this.store.selectSnapshot(DealerState.getDealerId);
    this.walletRestService.retrieveWalletAmount(dealerId).subscribe((genericResponseModel: GenericResponseModel) => {
      this.dealerAcctBalance = genericResponseModel.walletAmount;
      this.store.dispatch(new SetWalletBalance(this.dealerAcctBalance));
    }, (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you are asking what "routes" or URLs a user can have specific access too, I would recommend looking into implementing AuthGuards along with `canActivate` in your `routes` array to only allow access in certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my question. Could you kindly check it out?

Comment: Sure thing. You just need to write logic in your AuthGuard to only authorize users that are A, B, C, D etc. So within the `canActivate` function write some conditional checks to make sure users are a,b,c,d and if so return true, otherwise return false and provide an error message for the unauthorized access to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing an AuthGuard will allow you to write logic that only authorizes users A,B,C,D to have access to a certain route where the `change-plan` function is used for the specific URL. Inside the `canActivate` function is where you can write a few conditional checks to verify that a user is indeed A,B,C or D. If not, then access to that route (URL) is denied as the user is "unauthorized".

Since I'm not entirely sure what your conditional requirements are in terms of `id` or some property to determine whether users are A,B,C,D. Below is a pseudo code example, which I hope is helpful.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
   // get current sessions user to check authorization for
   user: any = this.userService.getCurrentUser();

   // dependency inject any services you might need to access users for checks
   constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {}

   canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
      // check if user is A,B,C,D (pseudo example based on ID)
      if (user.id !== 'A' || user.id !== 'B' || user.id !== 'C' || user.id !== 'D') {
         alert("Access denied.");
         this.route.navigate(['some-url']);
      }
      // otherwise user is A,B,C,D and authorized to access route
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, it works! I do have some question tho. What if I do another approach which is to just hide the button for users that don't have access? Think it would work too? I included the .html and .ts file in the question.

Comment: @PaulDickson Ok great! I'm glad it worked for you. Yeah that implementation would work, instead of generating an `alert()` or "unauthorized access" message. Just grab the button from the DOM and visually hide it with CSS instead of generating an alert for unauthorized users.